# how to iterate for various iterators on a lambda fuction?

Tags: python, lambda

This is more a code optimization question. Lest say that we have this easy lambda function:

```
a = (lambda x, y, z: 23 * x + y ** z)
```

It is easy to evaluate for fixed values and we can even iterate something like:

```py
for i in range(5, 10):      
       print(a(i, 2, 4))

131
154
177
200
223
```

So my question is how would be the best way to assign iterable values to not only `x` (i), but also to `y` and `z` so that the function will evaluate for example `y for j in a range(...)` and `z for k in a range(...)` (I mean any range)?

Comment: Not sure what is your question... Do you mean like three `for` loops? What values exactly you want to pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to iterate over a range of value use zip()

Using Zip function you can do this:

```
a = (lambda x, y, z: 23 * x + y ** z)

for i,j,k in zip(range(21,30), range(11,20), range(1,10)): # Change this as per your need
    print("For i =", i, "j =", j, "k =", k, ":", a(i, j, k))
```

Output:

```
For i = 21 j = 11 k = 1 : 494
For i = 22 j = 12 k = 2 : 650
For i = 23 j = 13 k = 3 : 2726
For i = 24 j = 14 k = 4 : 38968
For i = 25 j = 15 k = 5 : 759950
For i = 26 j = 16 k = 6 : 16777814
For i = 27 j = 17 k = 7 : 410339294
For i = 28 j = 18 k = 8 : 11019961220
For i = 29 j = 19 k = 9 : 322687698446
```

If you want to use combination of all value, you can use list comprehension like this:

```
a = (lambda x, y, z: 23 * x + y ** z)

print([a(i, j, k) for i in range(1,3) for j in range(1,3) for k in range(1,3)])
```

To find all possible values for all three parameters in range (1,3):

```
[24, 24, 25, 27, 47, 47, 48, 50]
```

Comment: In print, don't use string concatenations, use the multi-param of print : `print("For i =", i, "j =", j, "k =", k, ":", a(i, j, k))` It joins with space

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip` and set your convenient range value to get your desired result.

```
[a(i, j, k) for i, j, k in zip(range(1, 4), range(4, 7), range(7, 10))]
```

Output

```
[16407, 390671, 10077765]
```